# How to properly align logic operator?

Tags: align

I've been having trouble aligning these equations correctly
[image]
The`\iff`, `=`, `\ne` and `\land` need to be aligned, but I also need the things around them to not touch the `\land` and touch the equal/not equal instead, like

`a=b   and   c=d`

```
\begin{align*}
\phantom{\iff} &\frac{a}{b}&=\frac{c}{b}
&\land  
a&\ne c \\[1mm]

\iff &\frac{a}{b}+\left(-\frac{a}{b}\right)&=\frac{c}{b}+\left(-\frac{a}{b}\right) 
&\land
a+(-a)&\ne c+(-a) \\[1mm]

\iff &0&=\frac{cb+(a)b}{bb} 
&\land 
0\ne c+(-a)
\end{align*}
```

I'm new to latex so any other advice would be welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  `alignat` is more appropriate for this construction than `align`, so that's what I've used.  There should be no blank lines in math, so I've made those lines "comments" to give a visual break.  I've also added explicit spaces around the `\land` to set it off.  The real challenge is getting all the `&` in the proper order (and number).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{alignat*}{6}
  &&\frac{a}{b}&=\frac{c}{b}
  &&\quad \land \quad
  &a&\ne c \\[1mm]
%
\iff &&\frac{a}{b}+\left(-\frac{a}{b}\right)
  &=\frac{c}{b}+\left(-\frac{a}{b}\right) 
  &&\quad \land \quad
  &a+(-a)&\ne c+(-a) \\[1mm]
%
\iff &&0&=\frac{cb+(a)b}{bb} 
  &&\quad \land \quad
  &0&\ne c+(-a)
\end{alignat}
some following text
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]